# extjs "helloworld" example, does not run?

Tags: html, sencha-touch, xampp, extjs

According to the example in [this website](http://www.sencha.com/learn/getting-started-with-ext-js-4), I followed the steps, but I dont get any output in the browser.

As Stated in the example, the file "index.html" should be in the following path

'D:\xampp\htdocs\helloext\extjs\index.html'

and its"index.html" contents are the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Ext</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

when I run this example in both Chrome or FireFox, however, there is not output to be displayed.

Please guide me to have this samll example run correctly

Comment: More info needed. What are the contents of app.js? Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: actually inside D:\xampp\htdocs\helloext\extjs     there is no such file named app.js

Comment: can u tell me how should i know if there are errors or not??? the browser is just displaying white page....Sorry I'm new to this extjs and Ihave just started yesterday

Comment: Typically you will be notified of javascript errors in the browser status bar. I'd recommend developing using Google Chrome and its built-in developer tools, or using Firefox with the Firebug plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow the instructions at the end of section 2.1 (Application Structure)? You need to create the app.js file:

> Now you're ready to write your application code. Open app.js and
>   insert the following JavaScript code:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'HelloExt',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Hello Ext',
                    html : 'Hello! Welcome to Ext JS.'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: now, index.html juat contains the code I posted AND app.js just contains the code you posted and both files are located in D:\xampp\htdocs\helloext\extjs\          But I dont know why in the TYPE column in my windows, index.html is of type FireFox html document??

Comment: Well, Firefox is likely set as the default application to open HTML files.

Comment: ok, now i'm using Chrome. and when I try this  http://localhost/helloext/extjs/app.js      the browser just display the code u posted

Comment: oh, now it worked..i should have placed both index.html and app.js inside helloext and not inside extjs, though, you helped me to know what to write inside app.js. Thanks